# How do you make modal ProgressBar using C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, window, progress-bar

I am aware that `ShowDialog` will let me have the modal behavior and

```
progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
await Task.Run(action);
progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

Would let me have easy progress bar.

However, the progressBar above is not modal so user can touch around the UI action is taking place, and I would like to prevent that. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the progress bar into a modal dialog (can be configured/styled to be virtually just the content, relevant properties are `WindowStyle`, `ResizeMode` and `AllowsTransparency`, which should be set to `None`, `NoResize` and `True`, respectively i think...).

Comment: Hi H.B. Thank you very much for replying. Would you mind elaborating on this? I was not able to find a way to make wpf modal ialog